Angular RxJs: BehaviorSubject trigger http request, http request trigger subject.next
i have problem about circular dependency.
Tried to use switchMap(() => EMPTY), take(1). This solution works, but it's not a good solution.
Example code below:
P.S. ConstructorGeneratorService create field. When field is created, i need to update draft on backend and update my local state (subject)
// api.service.ts

export class AdminDraftFacade {
  private readonly adminDraft = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  readonly adminDraft$ = this.responseSubject.asObservable();
  readonly draft$: Observable<any> = this.adminDraft$.pipe(
      map(ud => ud.draft),
  );

  updateAdminDraft(draftId, draft) {
      this.api.updateAdminDraft(draftId, draft).pipe(
          tap(draft => this.adminDraft.next(draft)),
      ).subscribe();
   }
}

// some.component.ts

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly adminDraftFacade = inject(AdminDraftFacade);
  private readonly adminDraft$ = this.adminDraftFacade.adminDraft$;
  private readonly draft$ = this.adminDraftFacade.draft$;

  ngOnInit() {
        this.constructorGeneratorService.fields$
            .pipe(
                switchMap(field => this.updateDraft$(field)),
            )
            .subscribe();
  }


    private updateDraft$(field) {
        return this.draft$.pipe(
            tap(draft => {
                const updatedFields = this.transformFields(this.handleFieldChange(field, draft.fields || []));
                this.adminDraftFacade.updateAdminDraft(this.draftId, {
                    ...draft,
                    fields: updatedFields,
                }),
            }),
        );
    };

    private transformFields(fields: FieldInterface[]): FieldInterface[] {
        return fields
            .map(field => {
                if (!field.order && field.order !== 0) {
                    field.order = this.order.size;
                }

                return field;
            });
    }

    private handleFieldChange(field: FieldInterface, fields: FieldInterface[]): FieldInterface[] {
        const idx = fields.findIndex(item => item.id === field.id);

        if (((idx && idx !== -1) || idx === 0) && fields) {
            fields[idx] = field;
        } else {
            fields.push(field);
        }

        return fields;
    }
}


Angular 17, if signals can help, please tell me how :)

Have you tried using switchMap? https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap

If I get your problem correctly, this should do it:
SomeComponent:
...
private updateDraft(field) {
    this.adminDraftFacade.draft$.pipe(
      first(),
      switchMap((draft) => {
        const updatedFields = this.transformFields(
          this.handleFieldChange(field, draft.fields || [])
        );
        return this.adminDraftFacade.updateAdminDraft(this.draftId, {
          ...draft,
          fields: updatedFields,
        });
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
...

AdminDraftFacade:
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AdminDraftFacade {
  private readonly adminDraft = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  readonly adminDraft$ = this.adminDraft.asObservable();
  readonly draft$: Observable<any> = this.adminDraft$.pipe(
    map((ud) => ud.draft)
  );

  updateAdminDraft(draftId, draft) {
    return this.api.updateAdminDraft(draftId, draft).pipe(tap((draft) => this.adminDraft.next(draft)));
  }
}

The last updated draft response is saved in the AdminDraftFacade.adminDraft BehaviourSubject by the tap operator after the request was send.
